# Compute Probability of a Multivariate Normal Distribution over Polytope

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, polytopes

I have a Multivariate Normal Distribution with the mean vector $\boldsymbol\mu\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the covariance matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ given as
$$
f(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol\mu,\boldsymbol\Sigma) = 
\det(2\pi\boldsymbol\Sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol\mu)^{{{\!\mathsf{T}}}} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol\mu) \right)
$$
Now, I want to compute the probability that a realization of $\boldsymbol{x}$ lies in a given polytopic set of the form
$$
\mathcal{P} = \left\{ \boldsymbol{x}  \;\middle|\; \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} < \boldsymbol{b}   \right\}
$$
where the matrix $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} $ and the vector $\boldsymbol{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $ describes $m$ half-spaces and therefore a convex set.

The probability which I want to compute is given as
$$
\Pr(\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} < \boldsymbol{b}) = \int_\mathcal{P} f(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol\mu,\boldsymbol\Sigma) \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{x}
$$

How can I compute/approximate this integration numerically in MATLAB or Python for a given mean $\boldsymbol\mu$, a given covariance $\boldsymbol\Sigma$, and a given set $\mathcal{P}$. In my problem, the variable $\boldsymbol{x}$ has around 10 to 100 dimensions.

Comment: some references for this problem are provided here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380547/quadrature-methods-for-high-dimensional-gaussian-integration

Comment: Thank you for the references. However I am not sure if this is the same problem, because the support is the whole space and not a polytope. Did I miss something here?